# JavaScript heap out of memory error on Angular[11] build

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm facing a 'JavaScript heap out of memory error' error when I try to build the Angular App with a command

> ng build --prod --output-hashing=all

Then, I've been finding a solution on the internet and found a lot of recommends from the Stackoverflow to use

> node --max_old_space_size=5120 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

But it is not working for me.

When I use this command I can get rid of **memory** issue but I face with a ton of error instead which all about **"not a known element"** and **"cannot bind to 'ngModel'"** issues

For example,

```
error NG8001: 'nz-page-header-extra' is not a known element:
1. If 'nz-page-header-extra' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of 
 this module.
2. If 'nz-page-header-extra' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to 
  the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3   <nz-page-header-extra style="padding-top: 0.5rem">
```

or

```
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

12         [(ngModel)]="searchValue"
```

Note, the 'ng build --prod --output-hashing=all' used to work before, but it is not working after the project has more features.

My Angular dependencies

```
"@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
"@angular/cdk": "^12.1.4",
"@angular/common": "~11.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "~11.2.9",
"@angular/core": "~11.2.9",
"@angular/forms": "~11.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.9",
"@angular/router": "~11.2.9",
```

Comment: where is `nz-page-header-extra` dependency.

Comment: Also be sure to declare nz-page-header-extra component into your module on the declarations array. And be sure to have FormsModule in your module imports array.

Comment: I did import everything. It works with "ng build --prod --output-hashing=all" but it likes a lot of modules are missing with "node --max_old_space_size=5120 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --output-hashing=all".

Comment: Have you tried with a newer NodeJS version (e.g. Node 16.x.x)?